# Problema al realizar pago con PayPal

Tags: android, android-studio, paypal

**Buenas, estoy integrando el sdk de PayPal a mi app Android. En el entorno de prueba , SANDBOX, funciona todo bien. El problema está a la hora de pasarlo a producción. Por algún motivo, no puedo realizar los pagos ni iniciando sesión ni usando una tarjeta. ¿Cómo lo hago?

**Gradle**:

```
//PayPal
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
```

**Layout**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mpsdkRegularLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width='match_parent'
        android:layout_height='50dp'
        android:layout_marginTop='25dp'
        android:gravity='center'
        android:text='Pagar'
        android:id="@+id/btnPagas"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width='match_parent'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'
        android:id='@+id/mp_results'
        android:paddingTop='50dp'/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Actividad**:

```
public class PagosSuscripcion extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b;

    //Entorno Pruebas:
    ///private static final String CONFIG_ENVIROMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
    //private static final String CLIENTE_ID = "idClientePrueba";

    //Entorno Producción:
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIROMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
    private static final String CLIENTE_ID = "idClienteProducción";
    
    //Para controlar el pago
    private static final int ESTADO_PAGO = 1;

    //Configuraciones
    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIROMENT)
            .clientId(CLIENTE_ID)

            //configuracion minima del ente
            .merchantName("Mi tienda")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(
                    Uri.parse("https://www.mi_tienda.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(
                    Uri.parse("https://www.mi_tienda.com/legal"));

    PayPalPayment cosaAComprar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagos_suscripcion);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPagas);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cosaAComprar = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("0.1"), "USD",
                        "Suscripción", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(PagosSuscripcion.this,
                        PaymentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, cosaAComprar);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ESTADO_PAGO);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    // informacion extra del pedido
                    System.out.println(confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    System.out.println(confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject()
                            .toString(4));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Orden procesada.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            System.out.println("El usuario canceló el pago.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Si intento iniciar sesión para realizar el pago, sucede lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando uso mi tarjeta, pues sucede esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi App en Live:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me está funcionando? Gracias

Comment: tenes configurado para recibir esos pagos? y probaste usar la api Rest?

Comment: ¿Cómo se configura eso? Y no, no he probado con la apiRest @RamiroBarone

Comment: tenes toda la documentacion, para usar skd, javascript o api rest, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/ justo estos dias estoy aplicando esa api y no probe el sdk pero si la api rest y no tuve problemas

Comment: El problema es que no has configurado recibir pagos...

Comment: Y, ¿Cómo lo configuro @Jorgesys?

Comment: Se puede con paypal? yo tenia entendido q no , q solo g2pay de google. Creo q lei que ya no habia soporte de paypal para moviles, haber si alguien explica.

Comment: Pues, resulta que comuniqué mi duda con el soporte de PayPal y pues me dijeron que ya no funcionará más a partir del mes que viene así que, no funciona. @OsAndNoTi

Comment: pero no uses el sdk para movil, utiliza las api rest.

Comment: Pues, esa es la cosa jamás he usado cUrl ni Postman. Ese es el porqué implementé el SDK @RamiroBarone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El [PayPal-Android-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) ha sido "deprecated" por 2 años. Soporte caduca por completo después del 7 de diciembre

La única solución con un SDK nativo es el Braintree SDK de PayPal. Aquí algo de información: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64808583/2069605